# Grails Hibernate Criteria: Get the originial table entry

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria

**Solved: Changing the join-type to INNER_JOIN**

I'm trying to get the original table-entry of a domain class after executing a hibernate criteria.

For example:
The domain class A got a hasMany association to the domain class B.
The entity of A with the id 1, got two entities of B with the ids 11 and 12.

I'm executing the following criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class)
criteria.createAlias("Bs","B",CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("B.property", "%"+something+"%")

def list=criteria.list().unique()
```

Now I have a result set with all entities of A, which got an entity of B, which fullfilles the criteria.

But the results of A are different to the original entities of A, with regard to the hasMany relation to B. The entities of B, which not fullfilles the criteria are missing.

For example: The entity A with id 1 only got the entitie B with id 11.

Even if I execute a

```
def newA=A.findById(list[0])
```

the `newA` only got the B entity with the id 11. And the 12 is missing.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See: http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/06/querying-by-association-redux.html and http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7087

Try this:

```
def list = A.withCriteria {
    createAlias("bs", "aliasedBs")
    like("aliasedBs.property", "%something")
}
list.bs // will contain ALL items of the association, independent of the query
```

Comment: I always save with flush:true. If i execute def newA=A.findByName(list[0].name) the result got all associated instances.

Comment: What do you mean? The save action?

Comment: Yes, we need more information, since `withCriteria` will not return partial associations. The issue is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Oh I see, that there might be some bugs floating around in the release candidate: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7087. Are you using grails 1.3.6, 1.3.7 or 2.RC1?

Comment: I added the creation part. Im using Grails 1.3.7